Primrose way meaning
There’s a phrase “primrose path” (came from Shakespeare) which means the pursuit of pleasure that brings disastrous consequences. Does “primrose way” have the same meaning?

Are you asking if a variation of an idiom means the same? Depends on how close, like this one. If a misquote gets the same point across, it should be okay except for scolds. I'd also use "primrose path" for any future that masks a problem.

"Primrose way" is also in Shakespeare, in Macbeth ("primrose path" is in Hamlet) and they seem to mean similar things. But it would be useful to see where you saw "primrose way"; it occurs in many places since and it might be used in another way, e.g. a more literal sense for a route with primroses along the side.

Google 2-grams would suggest that 'primrose path' is used almost 9 times as frequently.
